# How can I link to sections using JQuery Pagination

Tags: jquery

I am using a simple pagination I found from another post, [jquery-pagination](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm). How do I link to certain sections of the pagination from other parts of the website.  For example, the user should be able to click on the link at the top of the page and go to a different part of the pagination.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination) I could find for it, and tried to use `$("#News-Pagination").trigger('setPage', [4]);` but could not get this to work.

Comment: Is your ID actually called `#News-Pagination`?

Comment: There's demo code of the event handlers at https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination/blob/master/src/demo/demo_events.htm. But when I loaded it into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/JcjJw/) the `Set to 2` button didn't work. So I suspect it's broken.

Comment: No that is not the actuall ID I used.  That is the exact same problem I had when I tried it, I just thought I was doing it incorrectly.  Any ideas on how to fix this, or am I just out of luck on this one?

Comment: Should I look at another pagination plugin, or is there a way to fix the one I am using?